# Gear cables replacement - inline barrel adjusters

Tags: shimano, gears

I'm in the process of ordering replacement gear cables for my road bike which has 105-5800 groupset. My existing cables have inline barrel adjusters and I was wondering:

1. Are the inline barrel adjusters reusable? (I'm not opposed to replacing even if they are)
2. If I have a barrel adjuster on the rear derailleur, do I really need an inline adjuster as well? (I need to verify setup for front derailleur)
3. Is there an optimal position on the cable for them to be installed?

Comment: I prefer to have them near the top of the down tube, if geometries permit.  But many modern bikes have "haywire" cable patterns and they have to go where they fit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Barrel adjusters are reusable.
More useful for the front mech which doesn't have any on-the-fly adjustment.
And useful for the rear mech for quick adjustment without having to get out of the saddle.

Comment: Nice answer, just updated the question slightly.

Comment: ad3) The best place to have them is next to the handlebar within easy reach.

Comment: Thanks.
And yes - there is an optimal position. 
Too high up the gear cable and they look a bit "silly" as they encroach towards the brake lever.
Too low and they might ping the frame over bumps and be a little low to reach.
The optimal place (on new bikes anyway) is in front of the head tube. But in reality - it is where you feel they look and function best.

Comment: If the shifter cables run under the bar tape together with the brake cables the best place imho would be shortly out from the tape. If the shifter cables run freely from the levers I'd place the adjuster in about half-way to the downtube.